# Very strange errors while using cout in module file

Tags: c++, module, c++20, iostream

Sorry, I couldn't make an MRE, the error doesn't happen in the cut code, but I will cut the code as much as possible.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Functions.h"

using namespace std;

import TNode;

//USE C++20
int main()
{
    string line;
    cout << "Enter line:\n";
    getline(cin, line);
    TNode<char> head = stringToBinaryTree(line);
    line;
}
```

Functions.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using namespace std;

import TNode;

TNode<char> stringToBinaryTree(string s);
```

Functions.cpp

```
#include "Functions.h"

using namespace std;

TNode<char> stringToBinaryTree(string s) {
    if (s.size() == 0) return TNode<char>();
    TNode<char> result(s[0]);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        result.addChildren(s[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

TNode.ixx (cut)

```
module;

#include <iostream>

export module TNode;

export{
    template <class T> class TNode;
}

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class TNode {
    T value;
    TNode<T>* leftChildren;
    TNode<T>* rightChildren;
    TNode<T>* Parent;
public:
    TNode();
    TNode(const T value);
    TNode(TNode<T>& parent, const T value);
    TNode(const TNode<T>& copyTree);

    TNode<T>& operator=(const TNode<T>& source);

    TNode<T>* addChildren(T value);

    TNode<T>* left() const;
    TNode<T>* right() const;
    TNode<T>* parent() const;

    T getValue() const;
    void setValue(T value);
};

//then only the used methods and functions

template <class T> TNode<T>::TNode(TNode<T>& parentNode, const T value) {
    this->value = value;
    leftChildren = nullptr;
    rightChildren = nullptr;
    Parent = nullptr;
    if (parentNode.getValue() >= value) {
        if (parentNode.right() != nullptr) TNode(*parentNode.right(), value);
        else {
            parentNode.rightChildren = this;
            Parent = &parentNode;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (parentNode.left() != nullptr) TNode(*parentNode.left(), value);
        else {
            parentNode.leftChildren = this;
            Parent = &parentNode;
        }
    }
}

template <class T> TNode<T>* TNode<T>::addChildren(T value) {
    TNode<T>* children = new TNode<T>(*this, value);
    return children;
}

template <class T> void recursionCopy(TNode<T>* dest, const TNode<T>* source) {
    dest->addChildren(source->getValue());
    //cout << "Added " << source->getValue() << "to destination"; //if uncomment this happens error C2995 and C2572
    //if (dest->parent()) cout << " with parrent " << dest->parent() << "\n"; //but if uncomment this while still have prev line uncommented its LNK2005 and LNK1169 errors now
    //else cout << "\n";
    if (source->left()) {
        //cout << "Goind to left with value " << source->left()->getValue() << "\n";
        recursionCopy(dest, source->left());
    }
    if (source->right()) {
        //cout << "Goind to right with value " << source->right()->getValue() << "\n";
        recursionCopy(dest, source->right());
    }       
}

template <class T> TNode<T>::TNode(const TNode<T>& copyTree) {
    value = copyTree.value;
    recursionCopy(this, &copyTree);
}

template <class T> T TNode<T>::getValue() const {
    return value;
}

template <class T> TNode<T>* TNode<T>::parent() const {
    return Parent;
}
```

The problem happens in the `recursionCopy()` function.

When I don't uncomment the `cout` code, there are no compilation or link errors.

When I uncomment the first line where I used `getValue()`, the compiler is getting MAD and saying the `operator!=` template is already defined. Why? I am not defining or using `operator!=`, but it gives me this error from the `<iosfwd>` file.

But the interesting part comes when I uncomment the second line with `parent()`, it causes linker errors with 8 functions, but in `Functions.obj` for some reason. Here one of the linker errors:

> "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Osfx(void)" (?_Osfx@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)" already defined in Functions.obj